# View Array contents in Qt Creator debugger

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator

I am using Qt on Ubuntu. When I debug I only see the very first value of the array in Locals and Watchers. How can I view all the array contents?

```
struct node
{
    int *keys;
    void **pointers;
    int num_keys;
    struct node *parent;
    int is_leaf;
    struct node *nextLevelNode;
};
```

It shows only the first key value in the debugging window.

Answer (score 15):

In Expression evaluator,
Try `(int[10])(*myArray)` instead of `(int[10])myArray`

Or, `*myArray@10` instead of `myArray@10`

Answer (score 8):

> It shows only the first key value,in the debugging window

I presume you're referring to the pointer keys, declared with `int *keys;`

The debugger doesn't know that this is an array: all it knows is that this is a pointer to an `int`. So it can't know how many values you want it to display.

What I've found, using the Qt Creator 2.1.0 debugger on Ubuntu, is that the following code allows me to see all 5 values:

```
int array1[5];
array1[0] = 2;
array1[1] = 4;
array1[2] = 6;
array1[3] = 8;
array1[4] = 10;
```

Whereas with this code, the debugger only shows the first value, exactly as you describe.

```
int* array2 = new int[5];
array2[0] = 20;
array2[1] = 21;
array2[2] = 22;
array2[3] = 23;
array2[4] = 24;
```

Aside: of course, the above code would be followed by this, to avoid leaking memory:

```
delete[] array2;
```

**Later**: This [Qt Developer Network Forum Post](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/forums/viewthread/5807/#35300) says that you can tell the debugger to display a pointer as an array:

> In Locals and Watchers, context menu of your pointer’s entry, select “Watch Expression”. This creates a new watched expression below.
>
> There, double click on the entry in the “Names” column, and add “@10” to display 10 entries.

This sounds like it should get you going.

Answer (score 7):

Just right-click on your variable, and choose `Change Value Display Format` and check `Array of 100 items`.

Answer (score 1):

In Qt for mac what worked for me was:

1. Add an expression evaluator for the desired variable (right click the variable on the debugger window then "Add expression evaluator for "var name here""

[image]

2. The array variable appears initially as a single value. Just change "var" to "var[start...end] and the array values appear.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Two dimensional arrays sometimes cannot be displayed by the [currently top voted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20619086/6405767). There is a work-around. First, declare a two-dimensional array as a one-dimensional array like this:

```
    int width = 3;
    int height = 4;
    int* array2D = new int [width*height];
    int x,y;
    for(x=width-1;x>-1;x--)
        for(y=height-1;y>-1;y--)
            array2D[x*height + y] = -1; // mark a breakpoint here!
    // add to expression evaluator: (int[3][4]) *array2D
    delete [] array2D;
```

Then add `(int[3][4]) *array2D` to the expression evaluator. Unfortunately you have to index the array your self, but you can write a special-purpose inline function or use another encapsulation method to make it slightly cleaner.