# View Array contents in QtCreator

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator

Is it possible to view the contents of an array in Qt Creator when debugging?

It seems to detect that my array is an array and not a pointer. Additionally, an arrow becomes available for me to click on as if to expand - but nothing shows after that.

[image]

When I tried it on `std::vector`, Qt Creator managed to display the contents as expected.

PS: I found [this old post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7533833/view-array-contents-in-qt-debugging-mode) about viewing array contents, but its over 2 years old and does not seem relevant anymore.

Comment: If you are using VS environment, try adding this into watch : `flags, 5` or `((bool*)flags), 5`. In case you are using CDB I think that could work, it works in VS. If GCC/GDB, you should look for _pretty printers_

Comment: If your array class and contents-class(es) are known in the current class, qtcreate should display your array contents. As you said, with clicking the arrow for expanding the array, the contents should be shown. What size is your array?

Comment: @SebastianLange was correct. The problem was that the array was too large to be displayed correctly (it was about 100 elements in length). Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean a regular array like

```
int array[20]
```

you can add a 'watch' manualy in this form:

```
(int[20])array
```

You can add it in your variables view.

Answer (score 1):

you can veiw the content of array 
by going to local and expression part

[image]

and click right and sellect add new expression evaluator
then add your array between watcher like

```
(int(*)[10])arr;
```

or

```
(int[10])(*arr);
```

now you can see each element at your array

[image]

this is faster than entering each element manual by adding *(arr + element number) at add new expression evaluator this is too bad if you have array of 1000 element or more