# Display pointer as array in Qt Creator with CDB for debugger

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator, windbg

**Edit 2:** If it's not possible, I will award the bounty to an answer that proves it (I mean provides some credible sources that back the claim that it's not possible).

---

Let's say I have a pointer to an array, for example:

```
int arr[3];
int *p = new int[3];
```

I can see all the elements of `arr`, but only the first element of `p`. How can I see all 3 elements of `p`?

I tried the various suggestions from the answers from [View Array contents in QtCreator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18966038/view-array-contents-in-qtcreator) and [View Array contents in Qt Creator debugger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7533833/view-array-contents-in-qt-creator-debugger), however they didn't work for me:

[image]

I assume this is because I'm on CDB, while the other 2 questions are for GDB. Is it possible to achieve the same for CDB?

**Edit:** I forgot to mention, but `p,3` also doesn't work.

Comment: Try `(int (&) [3])p`

Comment: @GreenScape CDB logs this error: `eERROR: Unable to add watch item "watch.1"/"(int (&) [3])p": Cannot add symbol '(int (&) [3])p': DEBUG_ANY_ID was returned as symbol index by AddSymbol.`

Answer (score 5):

Add into Expression Evaluator (menu Window->Views->Locals and Expressions)

```
(int(*)[3])p
```

That works fine in  Qt Creator 3.2.1 Based on Qt 5.3.2 (GCC 4.9.2, 64 bit) Built on May 10 2016 at 17:53:15.

Answer (score -1):

You can use *(p+1) and *(p+2), to access the other two element.

**Edit:**
@sashoalm You need to do this below:

```
int *pindex[3];
for(int j=0; j< 3;j++){
    pindex[j]= p+j;
}
```

Then you will be able to see all your p in the debugger.

Hope this helps.

Comment: That's not a solution at all. I already know about `p[1]` and `p[2]`. I need it to work for arrays of hundreds of elements.

Answer (score -2):

To see all element of *p:

1. Right Click On Local and Expressions.
2. enter *(p+1) and *(p+2).

So, You can see all three elements.

Comment: If you're going to copy an existing answer you might pick one that hasn't been downvoted and doesn't answer the question satisfactorily.

Comment: Please don't copy others' answers, do some new contributions to SE